# How to show column arrow icon based on Dropdown selection in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-pipe

> Kindly see the below picture, there is a drop-down button called sort
>   where all the headers are there.if i select any of the header it
>   should display up and down arrow.now its displaying in all the
>   headers.

```
<th abs-table-header [sortable]="true" [sortableContent]="HeaderData[1].value">{{HeaderData[1].text}}</th>
<th abs-table-header [sortable]="true" [sortableContent]="HeaderData[4].value">{{HeaderData[4].text}}</th>
<th abs-table-header [sortable]="true" [sortableContent]="HeaderData[3].value">{{HeaderData[3].text}}</th>             
<th abs-table-header [sortable]="true" [sortableContent]="HeaderData[5].value">{{HeaderData[5].text}}</th>
```

> Here [sortable]="true" gives me both up and down arrow icon.so how can show that icon based on selection instead of displaying at all headers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could swap out the `<th>` with an `ngIf` based on the value of the dropdown.

```
<th *ngIf="sortSelectValue != HeaderData[1].text" abs-table-header>{{HeaderData[1].text}}</th>
<th *ngIf="sortSelectValue == HeaderData[1].text" abs-table-header [sortable]="true" [sortableContent]="HeaderData[1].value">{{HeaderData[1].text}}</th>
```

Comment: it's just hiding the icon but there is no effect onclick of dropdown.